# PowerShellLibJava is fetching invalid JSON token from java code in docker container

Tags: java, azure, docker, powershell, azure-cli

I am using PowerShellLibJava (https://github.com/Tuupertunut/PowerShellLibJava) in java code to fetch access token from azure.
Earlier it was working fine in docker container.
On windows machine, its working fine but when fetching in docker container it's providing invalid access token (binary content instead of JSON)

To login using command

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions -u <emailAddress> -p <password>
```

login successfully.

using this command through "executeCommands" to fetch token

```
az account get-access-token --resource-type ms-graph
```

groovy script and shell both are able to fetch valid access token in container but java code is failing to fetch the token.

Comment: @Tuupertunut , can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Fetching in a docker container it's providing an invalid access token (binary content instead of JSON)

The error shows that you are **not converting the JSON** while getting the **Access Token**.

#### 1. Using AZ-CLI

**you can convert the Access token from JSON.**

```
# Get Access Token
az  account  get-access-token  --resource  ms-graph  |  ConvertFrom-Json
```

#### 2. Using PowerShell

You can use the **Get-AzAccessToken** to get the Access Token of ms-graph

```
# Get Access Token
$graphToken =Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName MSGraph
```

#### Reference

[Compare](https://scomnewbie.github.io/posts/clivspowershellaccesstoken/) **get-access-token** and **Get-AzAccessToken**

Answer (score 0):

After deep investigation, I found that command response start with a utf8 BOM which was making JSON response invalid in the program code. Where as Windows PowerShell does handle BOM itself.